# How to create a DF based on a filter criteria across all the columns in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wanted to build a new DF based on the original DF and exclude all the columns which does not match the specified value. 
Below is the snippet I am working on.

```
val myDf = Seq(
("0:16:52:01.0000000", "0:16:59:25.0000000", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-19"),
("0:16:52:01.0000000", "0:16:59:25.0000000", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-19"), 
("0:16:52:01.0000000", "0:16:59:25.0000000", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-19")
).toDF("StartTime", "EndTime","StartDate","EndDate")

// i am trying something like this but it gives me all the columns from the original DF if there is a match. 
// But Wanted a way which will give just "StartTime", "EndTime" in the new DF.
myDf.columns.map(name => myDf.filter(s"$name like '%-%'"))
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly optimized version without mutable datastructures:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val timeCols = myDf.columns.map(col).filterNot(c => myDf.limit(1).filter(c like "%:%:%:%").isEmpty)
val newDf = myDf.select(timeCols:_*)
```

Maybe it's even enough the look for the column names containing `time`?

```
val timeCols = myDf.columns.filter(_.toLowerCase.contains("time")).map(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

come up with the below solution and it is working as I expect. Hopefully there could be a better solution and expect someone will post the optimized version.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
var timeCols = ArrayBuffer.empty[String] 
myDf.columns.map(x => if (myDf.filter(s"$x like '%-%'").head(1).isEmpty) timeCols += x)
val newDf = myDf.select(timeCols.head, timeCols.tail: _*)
newDf.show(5)
```